# CSS Page Break Before (Left & Right) Not Working

Tags: html, css

My goal is to print from the browser a series of letters.  For users who print the letters on both sides of the paper, I want to ensure that a new letter never starts on the back side of the previous letter.  Letters vary in length, some being 2 pages and others being 3.

It appears that the following CSS should resolve this:

```
page-break-before: left
```

However, when I put together a sample, it does not seem to work as expected.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2.left { page-break-before: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 class="left">New Section</h2>
<h2 class="left">New Section</h2>
<h2 class="left">New Section</h2>
<h2 class="left">New Section</h2>
<h2 class="left">New Section</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

**I'd expect the code to print out 9 pages, with a blank page between each to force the next one to the "left".**  In reality the print preview simply shows each h2 on it's own page with a single blank page at the beginning.

Am I misunderstanding how this CSS works or is my implementation incorrect?

*Update: I've tested this in Chrome, Safari, and Opera - none of which seem to work as expected.*

Comment: **Note**: Internet Explorer and Firefox do not support the property values "left" or "right".

Comment: Try interleaving additional elements between your headers, also with `page-break-before`. Dirty, but might work.

Comment: Oriol: Thanks but that didn't seem to make a difference.  The same dynamic happens with the additional elements being on their own page but never a blank page inserted.  Here's what I tried: http://pastebin.com/hPyxTat9

Comment: Support for these properties is broken in most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only browsers that currently support:

```
page-break-before: left|right
page-break-after: left|right
```

Are Internet Explorer, Edge, and Opera Mini
(Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break)

Other browsers typically default to "always" if "left" or "right" is used which explains the results in the initial question.